# Need an Algorithm Such that $\sum_{k-i}^{j}{A[k]}$

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, computer-science, contest-math, recursive-algorithms

I need an algorithm for real application.

Suppose we have array A (positive & negative ) numbers. we want to find index i, j such that $\sum_{k-i}^{j}{A[k]}$ has the lowest difference to zero. can anyone hint or give me a efficient algorithm or pesudocode for it?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is this algorithm for? :)

Comment: Why the [tag:asymptotics] tag?

Comment: I have spent at least an hour on this problem, but cannot make it better then $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$. The only improvement to brute force method that I can cotribute is that computing all the sums takes me $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$ and not $\mathcal{O}(n^3)$ time (first, compute sums $\sum_{k = i}^j A[k]$, where $i=j$, then those where $i = j - 1$ ... ).

Comment: What do you mean by 'lowest difference to zero'?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an $\mathcal{O}(n\log n)$ answer.

For example, let be A = [2, 4, 6, -9, 12, -20]. We assume zero-based indexing.

```
alg(A):
   cumulativeSums = [0]

   for x in A:
       y = the last element of cumulativeSums
       add y + x at the end of cumulativeSums

   sort cumulativeSums
   minDifference = infinity

   for i = 1, ... , length(cumulativeSums) - 1:
       dif = cumulativeSums[i] - cumulativeSums[i - 1]
       minDifference = min(minDifference, dif)

   return minDifference
```

Everything except for sorting is linear. In our example we compute

```
cumulativeSums = [0, 2, 6, 12, 3, 15, -5]
```

After sorting, we have

```
cumulativeSums = [-5, 0, 2, 3, 6, 12, 15]
minDifference = 3 - 2 = 1
```

Algorithm returns the absolute value of the optimal sum. One can easily modify it if he wants it to return a real sum and corresponding $i$ and $j$.